# unity create slider without canvas parent?

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas, slider

I want to create health-bar slider for each enemy instantiated, and I also want it to be destroyed when the enemy is destroyed.

So I want the slider to be a child of the enemy, but then it wont show on screen. Is there any way I can get the slider to work when it isn't canvas child?

Comment: A UI element must be a child of a Canvas. You should mention if this is for a 2D or 3D game. For example, the Slider should follow 2D Sprite image or 3D model.....

Comment: The alpha cutout shader also works wonders. I made [these shaders](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/vfx/shaders/alpha-cutout-shaders-16429) so that it looked a little nicer, but its the same idea: a gradient alpha texture and only drawing the parts below the current health percentage.

Comment: Would it be okay to assume that what you want is to display overlaying health bars for your enemies (that is, the health bar is on top of all the scene objects and will not be occluded), and each health bar chases the enemy that it displays information for? It that is the case, you can try to put all your health bars in a screen overlaying canvas, and write a manager to adjust their (2D) positions in the canvas to reflect the (3D) positions of the enemies.

Comment: Thanks! I handled it by making the health-bars instantiate in the same script of the health components.